# kivy gives this EROR 'Unable to get a Window, abort.'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

kivy gives this ERROR '`Unable to get a Window, abort.`' How can I fix it?

I have seen some topics in this site but they were not helpful.

Comment: Can you provide full error traceback?

Comment: [CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\javan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\javan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.